# Drop-down list separating from migration dialogue box

Tags: bug, close-dialog

When I was attempting to migrate a question, I started moving the box, and this is what happened:

[image]

It does still respond to the mouse when I hover over it.  Closing the box also close this list as well.

- Browser: Chrome 39.0.2171.95
- OS: Windows 7